# Only show documents that were not opened

Tags: document-library

I need to show a user only the documents that they haven't opened.

Is there anything out of the box or what is the best view to achieve this?

I am using Sharepoint 2013 on premises.

Comment: if user view a document ( either downloading a read only copy or checked out the document) then it  should not see it in a particular view, right?

Comment: yes, this is what I would like.